# .htaccess rewrite - redirect to a php file that redirects, want to keep original URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now when the user types something like

```
site.com/shirt/shirtid
```

They are redirected by a RewriteRule that says

```
RewriteRule ^shirt/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)$ /utils/phurl/redirect.php?alias=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which then redirects them to the page which is assigned that alias.

When the PHP redirection happens (via header(Location:$url)), however, it changes the url from site.com/shirt/shirtid to the very long URL that I wanted shortened. Is there a way I can maintain the original URL through this entire redirection process?

E.g. User goes to site.com/shirt/shirtid, redirection process happens, URL in address bar remains site.com/shirt/shirtid

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a redirect header through PHP, you are going to, by default, cause a page-load redirection.  You can of course redirect to any URL format you want.  I don't see how you can make it the same as the original URL however, as this would stick you in an infinite redirect loop.

It sounds to me like in PHP that you don't actually want to do a redirect, but rather include some set of page logic conditionally based on the alias value (basically a front-controller pattern).